# Protractor check radio button

Tags: protractor

I want to check a radio button in my protractor script and the html is as follows:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="relation.type" value="personal" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="7">
```

How can I write an expression chosing this radio button over another in a list of radio buttons? another button that I do not want to choose looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="relation.type" value="employee" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="8">
```

so what is unique between the two is the "value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
    var expectedRadio = element.all(by.model('relation.type'));
    expectedRadio.each((eachRadio) => {
        eachRadio.getAttribute('value').then((valueText) => {
               if (valueText == "personal")
               {
                //Do what you need
               }
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
element.all(by.model('relation.type')).get(1).getAttribute('value');
element.all(by.model('relation.type"')).get(2).getAttribute('value');
element.all(by.model('relation.type')).first().getAttribute('value');
element.all(by.model('relation.type"')).last().getAttribute('value');
```

Please also refer protractor documentation [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/locators)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   try {
        let btn = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-login/div[3]/label[2]'));
         browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', btn).then(async() => {
            console.log(' Radio Btn has been clicked.');
        });
       } catch (error) {
        console.log('Button is not clickable due ' + error);
      }
```